# How do open subsets of X/G look like?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

Let $G$ act continuously on $X$, where $X$ is a topological space.

So I wonder about how open subsets look like in $X/G$.

The action $a$ is defined as $a(g,x)=g.x$.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Subsets of $X / G$ are, by definition, collections of orbits of the $G$-action on $X$, but presumably you want something more?

Comment: it depends on $X$ and $G$. If you have, for example, $X=\Bbb{R}^2$ and $G:=SO(2)$ the group of orthogonal $2\times 2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix} \cos(t) & \sin(t) \\-\sin(t) & \cos(t) \end{pmatrix}$, then $\Bbb{R}^2/SO(2)$ is the circle with radius $||x||$ for $x \in \Bbb{R}^2$ (and is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$)

Answer (score 1):

The quotient space topology in the space of orbits $X/G$ is induced by the topology in $X$ via the projection $\pi \colon X \to X/G$ where $\pi(x) = Gx$. More specifically a subset $U \subset X/G$ is open if and only if $\pi^{-1} U$ is open.

Another way of saying this is that a set $\mathcal{O}$ of orbits is open if and only if $\bigcup \mathcal{O}$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The open sets of $X/G$ are precisely images of $G$-invariant open subsets of $X$, or if you want, images of saturated open subsets of $X$. This works for any quotient topology where the map $f\colon X \to Y$ is surjective. Note however that in the case of spaces of orbits $X/G$ the map $X\to X/G$ is moreover open, that is, the image of an open subset of $X$ is open, equivalently, the saturation of an open subset $U$ of $X$, being $\cup_{g\in G} g\cdot U$, is also open.

Equivalently, you can think in terms of closed subsets: the closed ones of $X/G$ are images of saturated($G$-invariant) closed subsets of $G$. In this case, the map $X\to X/G$ may not be closed, but it surely is if say $G$ is finite.

Comment: How could you come up with that the map is moreover open?

Comment: For open $U$ in $X$ we have $f^{-1}(f(U)) = \cup_{g \in G} g\cdot U$  open, so $f(U)$ is.